# After restoration of .stm file i unable to open emails.

Tags: database, exchange-2007, files

We use Exchange server 2007 as a mail server where mailboxes don`t synced to Outlook. We had some problems with a .stm file and we restored it. After that we unable to open any emails located in these shared mailboxes.

I have tried to restore .stm file from a .pst backup using ExMerge, but I am still unable to open all the “restored” files. ExMerge can see the corrupted files but why it does not recreate them? How else can I restore the mailboxes?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that there should be no .stm file in Exchange Server 2007. Additionally, you can't restore an Exchange mailbox database simply by restoring the files, AFAIK.

Comment: Did you use an Exchange-aware backup program to create your backup? Did you perform the restore using your backup program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EDB and STM are closely connected. So you need to restore not only the stm, but also edb and log files.

I would suggest to create a Recovery storage group, then mount the database in this group and merge all the mailboxes. This must restore all your lost data. But make a test before this with a couple of mailboxes.

Unfortunately i am not a pro, so i can`t advise a lot of perfect ways to solve the issue. You can find similar threads in this forum, or search in other like a msdn or technet. For instance i found this discussion: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/125bd7ed-e4ad-440c-8ebc-ec209eb3b766/trouble-reading-files-error-523-service-transaction-error?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

Hope it will help. Wish you to handle it :)